Cant run Local python lambda function using AWS toolkit
I have Intellij and AWS toolkit plugin installed in it. I want to run simple python lambda from project which has a structure as below.
Project_name

src

handler.py
client.py
.....


serverless.yml

Now I want to run the lambda function lcoally so I configure the AWS toolkit run-configuration as below. But it gives me error saying "cannot locate the handler" or says "Error: Lambda handler validation is in progress"

Could someone who have used the AWS toolkit to run the config locally help me here, what am I missing.
I tried changing the handler name to handler.get_handler  or src.handler.get_handler OR get_handler.
But cant get it working.
Other details-
I am using global python 3.11 as the interpreter here in the project and not venv.

considering you have insalled boto3 and requests package installed globally as you are trying to use global python not venv
change you Handler value from :
handler.get_handler

to
src/handler.get_handler

as your handler is inside the src directory, you can run you lambda locally.
I am using global python 3.12 but i created venv using following python command and activating it:
python -m venv venv

source venv/bin/activate

and installed boto3 and requests from requirements.txt file in root of the project using following command:
pip install -r requiremnts.txt

and set the Handler value as : src/handler.get_handler
Input:
{
  "test": "data"
}

i colud run the lambda locally and get following output:

note: make sure to try with both architectue x86_64 and arm64, x86_64 worked for me. kudos
